# Unable to establish SSL connection to LDAP from a windows server 2008 VM

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2008

I'm using LDAP admin to connect to an LDAP protected using SSL from a windows server 2008 VM but it kept saying the server is down. Pinging from the VM to the machine shows that it is up and when I run LDAP admin on my host machine with a windows 7 OS it works fine, any ideas what settings I should change on the server 2008 VM?

Comment: I assume you've walked through [this procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941846(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Comment: I'm not using active directory as my directory application

Comment: Pinging aside, can you telnet to port 636 (for LDAPS) or port 386 (for StartTLS), depending on which one you use? You won't get much with telnet, but it should show you if you can at least connect (better than ping).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able it get through to our LDAP by changing my VM's network setting. I was running bridged, when switched to NAT (effectively sharing my host computer's IP) I was then able to connect.

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your LDAP is not protected by a firewall or configured to disallow your VMs IP or domain for connections. If you are authorizing to the LDAP server, recheck your credentials.